# Insert rows to accommodate raw data of multiple strings within one cell separated by a comma and space

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to migrate data from one worksheet to another.

The data is in two columns; ‘Question’ (Col B, first question at B2) and corresponding ‘Answer’ (Col E, first answer at E2).
There are roughly 800 rows of questions. Some of the corresponding answers are multiple choice, structured as strings within one cell and separated by a comma and space ("3a, 3b, 3c" etc.).

In the target worksheet, the answers need to be structured such that each multiple choice answer has it’s own row.

My original approach was to textsplit the multiple choice answers, but autofilling led to each multiple choice answer giving a SPILL error, as the subsequent questions were occupying the space in which the multiple choice answers where spilling down into.

The only solution I can think of is using VBA to automatically add rows based on how many spilt cells there are (multiple choice answers range from two options to hundreds).

I can’t post data due to confidentiality, so I will describe what I need:

- E2:E889 in worksheet 1, copy and pasted into worksheet 2, starting at AX3
- Any answers that are multiple choice (I.e., containing the string ", ") are textsplit down in the same column, new rows are created to accommodate for the spilled cells
- D2:D889 in worksheet 1, copy and pasted in to worksheet 2, starting at A3.
- For the extra rows added for multiple choice, repeat the name of the question in column A of worksheet 2. For example, for every possible answer to “location" have a series of rows with the string ‘location’ in column A and each possible answer in column AX

Comment: Pls have a look to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183910/vba-script-to-count-string-insert-rows-copy-row-split-cell

Comment: @Blackcat thank you for showing me to this, unfortunately it is slightly too advanced/unrelated to my current problem for me to fully understand what is going on! I will try and wrap my head around it, but I could really use something more specific to my current predicament

Comment: Although it indeed could be done by VBA, it'll be pretty complex and probably not too quick. I'd use Power Query to transform the data. If you can post some sample data (don't need real data, just something with the same structure), we can help with that.

Comment: You can probably do it without VBA, but like @MátéJuhász said, you really need to show some sample data (doesn't have to be real data) for us to help you.

Comment: Sample data would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the questions are in column B. (D2:D889 is a typo)

```
Sub splitrows()
Dim Ssh As Worksheet, Tsh As Worksheet
Set Ssh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Tsh = Worksheets("Sheet2")
k = 3
lastquest = Ssh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastquest
  answerarray = Split(Ssh.Cells(i, 5), ", ")
  For j = 0 To UBound(answerarray)
    Tsh.Cells(k, "AX") = answerarray(j)
    Tsh.Cells(k, "A") = Ssh.Cells(i, "B")
    k = k + 1
  Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

It automatically find the end of the table (last row). The separator has to be a comma followed with a space. Sg. like this (Fine, Not bad, Horribly, Excellent). Then on Sheet2 in column A are the questions and column AX has the answers.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response - but this worked perfectly! How would I change code if I wanted to automatically fill in other columns? For example, designate each multiple choice answer with the string 'MultipleChoice' in column AJ?